# How can I parse an XML file given it's path in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to parse a XML file that a user choose through a file chooser. The problem I am having is on my input change event, the jquery is not being call.

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function(e){
    path = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: path,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
      });
```

});

function parseXml(xml)
{

```
head = xml;
alert('I reached here');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[type='file']").blur(function(){
    var path = $(this).val();
    alert(path);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: path,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(response) {
             parseXml(response);
        }
      });

});
});
function parseXml(xml) {
  //parse here
}
```

Comment: It still didn't work. Why is the event blur? Before when I had the event be change it would pop up alert message but not run the ajax call.I'm just wondering if i'm doing the ajax call right.